# Problems with connecting SQL server using PHP function mssql_connect

Tags: php, sql-server

I had a problems when trying to connect to SQL server using PHP function `mssql_connect`.

I try to connect is Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) version 10.50.6000.34.

When I connect to different SQL Server this is successful (SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Server Workgroup Edition version 9.00.5000.00).

> PHP Version 5.1.6.
>
> Apache is Apache/2.2.3 (Win32)
>
> DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8c mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.1.6.

I want to use `mssql_connect` because of old system.

What possibly could be a problem?

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read in detail what issue occurs where in your code.

Comment: The other SQL Server that you connect is also 64bit? I think problem is that you trying to connect to 64bit SQL Server via 32bit drivers. And, please, show us what errors you get.

Comment: Thank for your reply. After 2 days finding over internet im get rid of and asking my boss.it turn out that php bug over window environment.See more at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37232 now i keep to finding a solution